# Cannot use Get commands in Azure RM portal using powershell

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to create VM in resource manager portal using powershell. 
Get-AzureRmLocation,Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork,Get-AzureRmAvailabilitySet these commands cannot be used.It shows an error as "The term 'Get-AzureRmLocation' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function". Please let me know how to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Azure PS Cmdlets you're using?

Comment: I am using Azure powershell Version : 1.0.2

Answer (score 1):

They got rid of this command, despite my desperate attempts to get them to add it back. Use Get-AzureRmResourceProvider to find the supported Azure regions for each Resource Provider.

Comment: Thanks for the update. similarly I cannot use these commands too Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork,Get-AzureRmAvailabilitySet. Is there any option for this ?

Comment: Update to the latest version of ARM PowerShell, which is currently 1.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this Cmdlet has been removed! Please see the detailed discussion here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1299.

Based on this, it is recommended to use `Get-AzureRmResourceProvider`. As a fallback, you can also use `Get-AzureLocation` but I suspect that it makes use of Service Management module instead of Resource Manager.